# C++ int array memory error with 1000000 elements

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[1000000] = { 1, 2 };

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it in visual studio I get:

```
 (process 17300) exited with code -1073741571
```

With

```
int a[1000000] = {};
a[0] = 1;
```

I get the same error. If I lower it to 100000, it works fine. How can I avoid this error?

Comment: ***How can I avoid this error?*** Use a vector instead of a an array. Remember on windows / Visual Studio the default stack size is 1 MB total.

Comment: The error is a stack overflow use this web page to decode the error: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=-1073741571](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=-1073741571)

Comment: allocate on the heap instead

Comment: Declare the array as `static`.  Usually there is more memory available in the `static` area than on the stack.